# Unable to install 14.04. a few tries, a few issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So, yesterday, win 10 commited suicide again, by deleting internet protocols alone.

I'm fed up of this cancer, but I still game, so I want a dual boot

At first I was able to install linux alone, while my partitioning was GPT. It wouldn't see my others partitions. so I installed on the whole disk

When I installed win 7, it wouldn't let me chose a partition because it was GPT.

So I ran fixparts on terminal, and I deleted the traces of GPT partitionning.

I was able to install Win10.

I know I have to start with win if i don't want to install the GRUB

My computer has a GTX950M, so I usually have to do a NOMODESET=0
but i don't have the orange screen where you push "e" to add option. i have the blue screen, and I tried adding "nomodeset=0" but it still loads nouveau and freak out.

I manage to load the installer, but it bugged at apt updates or something like that.

15.05 didn't load either

I'm stuck, I don't know what else to try, but I can't live anymore with only win 10 that needs a format every few weeks

Comment: May rephrase the question since its not perfectly clear where exactly youre stuck. Are you stuck installing ubuntu or are you stuck booting the fresh install of ubuntu? "What does 15.05 didnt load either" mean?

Comment: Go with a mbr parition and do both with legacy boot.  You can make a usb boot with live linux installer that works with legacy.  Universal usb installer may also work.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck at installing. It worked once but I wasnt able to put Windows with it. 
Because of gpt. Now it's supposed to be in mbr but I lost the normal orange menu for the blue one.

It may have installed because it said it said it had apt-update problems, yet sais it finished. but I don't have any grub showing.

Sorry, english isn't my first language

15.05 just doesn't open the live cd or the install